# OpenCV Multithread with TBB for Video Processing

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, mutex

I'm currently trying to speed up and application that runs the SURF Algorithm to detect object on a video.

What I would like to do is use thread (probably boost thread) to speed up the process and have two threads:

- One that take an image and process it and when the algorithm terminates on the frame previously taken, take the current frame and run again
- The other one that focus on geeting image from the camera and display it.

If you want pseudo code here's what I have for now in the main function:

```
Mat imageReference, imageFromVideo;
imageReference = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

VideoCapture camVid(0);


namedWindow("Display video");
namedWindow("Display ref");
imshow("Display ref", imageReference);

// Surf algo on reference image
FastHessian fh(&image);
Surf surf(fh.GetIntegralImg(), fh.GetIptVect());
surf.descriptors(false);




while (true) {

    camVid >> imageFromVideo;

    // Surf on frame from video
    FastHessian fh2(&imageFromVideo); 
    Surf surf2(fh2.GetIntegralImg(), fh2.GetIptVect());
    surf2.descriptors(false);

    // Compare the two interest points from images
    vector<pair<InterestPoint, InterestPoint> > matches;
    matchIpoints(surf.getInterestPoints(), surf2.getInterestPoints(), matches);

    drawIPoints(&imageFromVideo, matches);

    int c = cvWaitKey(1);
    if ((char) c == 27) break;
    imshow("Display video", imageFromVideo);
    imshow("Display ref", imageRef);

}
```

I don't know really how to start with Multithread as I've never done it before. Should I do it with Mutex or with Semaphore? Is there is simple code to do this in few lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can go C++11 and use [`<thread>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread). Mutex is a semaphore with two possible values. Mutex will usually be sufficient.

I tried doing it the other way around (worker thread taking images from camera and main doing all the computing) and had a lot of problems - You can take a look at [header](https://github.com/morynicz/vision-of-movement/blob/master/inc/Catcher.hpp) and [main class code](https://github.com/morynicz/vision-of-movement/blob/master/src/Catcher.cpp). But good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will increase the speed of your program. OpenCV should use threads in object detection (at least in object detection using cascade classifiers, not usre about SURF). If you try to divide your CPUs/cores power on 2 different threads you may prevent OpenCV object detection function from using 2 or more cores. Generally it's hard to say which option will be faster. First of all i would check whether OpenCV is using more than one thread - to do this, just run some complex object detection (using frames from camera or on big image or video) and check (i.e. in task manager) whether you app is using more than 1 thread. If no - reinstall OpenCV with TBB, on mac just use `brew install opencv --with-tbb`,  for windows there is an instruction covering this, on linux it should be similar to mac solution.